# Is a number ring a Dedekind domain?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

I'm studying the number field sieve factorization method, but I am having some trouble with the definition of number ring.
I have found two different definitions:

- A number ring is a subring of a number field.
- A number ring is the subring of algebraic integers of some field.

They should not be equivalent, for example if we take the number field $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{5}]$, then for the first definition $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ is a number ring, but for the second definition, the number ring is $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right]$.

I'm pretty sure that with the second definition we have that a number ring is a Dedekind domain.
But what happens with the first definition?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: [Yes, every number ring is a Dedekind domain](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/numberfield/dedekind.html).

Comment: The first definition is given here:
http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/ant.pdf

Comment: TheSimpliFire, that site uses the second definition of number ring...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first definition is OK, but not much can be said about  number rings.

The second definition corresponds to what is usually the ‘ring of integers of the number field’, and in my opinion, it's better to use this terminology,to prevent any ambiguity.

To answer your  question, if the number ring doesn't satisfy the second definition, it can't be a Dedekind domain since it is not integrally closed.

Comment: Okay, but what kind of properties hold with the first definition? For example in many books there is written that with the first definition, if $R$ is a number ring and $p$ is a prime ideal, then $R/p$ is a field (and I could understand this if prime iff maximal...).

Comment: Only what can be said in general of integral extensions.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, in integral extensions is the equivalence prime ideal iff maximal ideal true?

Comment: If you mean in *general* ring integral extension, not necessarily. In number fields, it works for (non-zero) prime ideals because all rings have Krull dimension $1$. What can be said is that in an integral ring extension, Krull dimension is preserved (because of the *Goingup* and *Going down* theorems).

Comment: Mh, I'm not very practical with Krull dimension...
Only to be clear, let's take $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ that is root of some monic and irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Does the equivalence hold in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$?

Comment: In this case $\dim\mathbf Z[\alpha]=\dim\mathbf Z=1$.

Comment: "To answer your question, if the number ring doesn't satisfy the second definition, it can't be a Dedekind domain since it is not integrally closed."  That's not true: e.g. $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$ satisfies the first definition, not the second definition, and is a PID, hence a Dedekind domain.